# Fake microphone input for MATLAB

Tags: matlab, microphone

I'm working on a project on MATLAB that records sound and processes. I'm completely fed up of playing the same sounds over and over again during the development.

Is there some kind of way to "fake" the microphone i.e. playing a file on my computer and getting it in MATLAB with the same code I use to record with my mic?

Thanks for any help.

PS: I'm on Mac OS X Yosemite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you've implemented your code - if you post the relevant sections you'd be able to get more specific suggestions - but in general you might be able to replace the part of the code that captures input from the microphone with a call that reads a file from disk - `wavread` would be useful for this (http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/wavread.html).

If you're doing realtime stuff then it may or may not work, but if not then you could play the sound file in a third party application and use something to internally rewire the output to the input. [Soundflower](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/) is one tool that can do this, there are others.

Answer (score 1):

There are more pieces of the puzzle to address.

### If just an asynchronous mode of work is possible

If you just wish to work in silence and MATLAB process under development **does not require synchronisation** with the sound-replay ( not dependent on where the sound-sample starts & just needs "some" sound-related data to be input once the MATLAB code gets ready ), than the easiest way would be to plug a jack-connector into MIC and have the sound re-played in an endless loop by an external device ( MP3 player et al ) and enjoy the silence.

### In case a synchronous mode of operations is needed

In case your MATLAB code requires synchronised processing, aligned with  the start of the sound-sample and terminating the re-play process once MATLAB code is finished, then you need something a bit more complex than just a re-wired ( be it done physically or virtually ) sound delivery.

There are ways how to allow MATLAB communicate with external processes and thus allow triggering the synchronised events on the remote side ( sending a message alike <kbd>HeyPythonProcess.startTheSoundREPLAY()</kbd> ) and make the whole sound-processing both silent ( for example, the `python` audioservices can move sound-bytes into respective audiomixer paths under your full ( i.e. programmable ) control ) and fully synchronous ( via an event-driven, messaging layer, like **`ZeroMQ`** allows )
thus keeping the process as needed.

If this sounds complicated? Yes, it is complicated, but both realistic and possible. MATLAB allows inter-process communications / messaging in a fully autonomous multi-agent manner ( no subordination, indeed a fully autonomous mode of work ) and that gives you an immense power for the future, perhaps, once entering into distributed cloud/grid processing Projects.

### Use a side-effect of a bridged mode of MATLAB operations

There is also another synchronous way, to use python-MATLAB bridge, where python side "enforces" synchronicity ( controls the experiment ) and starts / stops the MATLAB part of the work ( thus aligning as a side-effect the replay with the MATLAB processing )

```
from pymatbridge import Matlab as aMATLAB   # get ready
'''                                         # 
mlab = aMATLAB()                            # a class instance ( empty )
'''                                         
mlab = aMATLAB( matlab = '...aMatlabCODE' ) # a class instance ( initialised )

mlab.start()                                # True once connected.
#
# start playing sound here
# ... and make MATLAB-beyond-the-bridge process it
# ...
# ....>>> |||||||||||||
#         vvvvvvvvvvvvv
results = mlab.run_code('a=1;')             # process code / vars
```

Comment: Re synchronous via loopback: you could of course use matlab as the player, then all your timing could be managed internally.